# what fasting for good health days/events are happening every month?

Tags: vedas, fasting, yogi, ekadashi, purnima

There a specific days we all know about like Ekadashi and I think Purnima, that happens every month, so im looking for fasting (for good health) days that happens every month like ekadashi, is there more than ekadashi and purnima ?